# Compress and Decompress sentence using vowel based encryption cipher

Tags: code-golf, cryptography

The aim is to parse a sentence and `compress/encrypt` it according to the rules below and then `decrypt` it using the `key`:

1. Remove all letters in a word before the first vowel is encountered. Example: `pigeon` becomes `igeon`.
2. All characters except alphabets should be kept in the sentence including numerals, punctuations, etc. Example: `200-storey building` becomes `200-orey uilding`.
3. Generate the shortest key array `char[] = {a,b,x,<your data>}` and write code to generate the original sentence using this key.

You need to write two functions: `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` which works for every sentence minimising the key-size.

Example 1:

> **Input:** The most technologically efficient machine man has ever
>   invented is the book. -Northrop Frye-
>
> **Output:** e ost echnologically efficient achine an as ever invented is e
>   ook. -orthrop e-
>
> **Example key:** {T,m,t,m,h,b,N,F,14,2,5}

Example 2:

> **Input:** "I need your clothes, your boots and your motorcycle. " - The
>   T-800 in Terminator 2: Judgment Day
>
> **Output:** "I eed our othes, our oots and our otorcycle. " - e -800 in
>   erminator 2: udgment ay
>
> **Example key:** {n,y,c,2,b,2,m,T,J,D,15}

**Winning Criteria:**

1. Write function `encrypt()` with input from `stdin` or `file` which generates `output` sentence and a `key` on `stdout` or `file` or `memory`.
2. Write function `decrypt()` with inputs the generated sentence and `key` from `encrypt()` and produces the original sentence.
3. This is `code-golf` so cumulative size of the two functions should be minimum. In case of tie-breaker, the generated key-size should be minimum.

Comment: Is there any specific format for the key array?

Comment: You can make `key` in any format of your choice, there is no rules for generating the `key`

Comment: In your first example, how does the key restore the 'Fry' of 'Frye'?

Comment: @githubphagocyte the key format and decoding logic entirely depends on you. You can form key in whatever format suitable for accurate decryption.

Comment: missing 'h' in the first example?

Comment: Define "*vowel*". Is `y` a vowel? How about `ü`? Or `ij` in Dutch texts? Or the Turkish dotless i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Perl5 61 + 30 = 91 <s>122</s> <s>211</s>

This is based on the same idea as [Comperendinous' Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/35764/11290) where the key is indeed the whole cleartext and I cannot see anywhere in the rules that prevent this so kudos to Comperendinous :)

```perl
sub encrypt{$k=$_=<>;s/(.*?)\b[^\W\daeiou]+/$1/gi;print$_.$k}
sub decrypt{$i=<>;$_=<>;print}
```

**Perl5 - 91 + 31 = 122**

Here the key is slightly larger, but it actually prrduces the cleartext from the chipertext with the key so I find this more kosher.

```perl
sub encrypt{$_=<>;$k="s/(.{$+[1]})/\$1$+/;$k"while s/(.*)\b([^\d\Waeiou]+)/$1/i;print$_.$k}
sub decrypt{$_=<>;eval<>;print}
```

Ungolfed (though  I've changed it to take parameters instead of two lines of text):

```perl
sub encrypt {
  my ($str) = @_;
  my $key = '';
  while( $str =~ s/(.*)\b([^\d\Waeiou]+)/$1/i ){
    $key = "\$str=~s/(.{$+[1]})/\$1$2/;$key";
  }
  ($str, $key);
}

sub decrypt {
  my ($str, $key) = @_;
  eval $key;
  $str;
}
```

**Perl5 - 114 + 75 + 22 (shared) = 211**

```perl
sub encrypt{$_=<>;@k=m/\b$x/ig;push@_,$+[1] while s/(.*?)\b$x/$1/i;print$_.join'',(@_,@k)[map{$_,$_+@k}0..$#k],$/}
sub decrypt{$i=<>;$_=<>;%k=m/(\d+)$x/g;print map{$k{$%++}|(),$_}split//,$i}
$x='([^\d\W\daeiou]+)'
```

With both functions chipertext is always output/input first, then the key.

Examples:

```
Input: 
The most technologically efficient machine man has ever invented is the book. -Northrop Frye-

Output:
e ost echnologically efficient achine an as ever invented is e ook. -orthrop e-
0Th2m6t31m38m41h61th63b69N77Fry

Input:
"I need your clothes, your boots and your motorcycle. " - The T-800 in Terminator 2: Judgment Day

Output:
"I eed our othes, our oots and our otorcycle. " - e -800 in erminator 2: udgment ay
3n7y11cl18y22b31y35m50Th52T60T73J81D
```

Ungolfed code:

```perl
# credit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/71895/1565698
sub zip {
    my $pivot = @_ / 2; 
    return @_[ map { $_, $_ + $pivot } 0 .. $pivot-1 ];
}

my $consonants = '([^\d\W\daeiou]+)';

sub encrypt {
  my $str = <>;
  my @matches = $str =~ m/\b$consonants/ig;
  my @indexes = ();
  while( $str =~ s/(.*?)\b$consonants/$1/i ) {
    push @indexes, $+[1]; # @+ has the match positions starting at 1
  }
  my $key = join('', zip(@indexes, @matches));
  print "$str$key\n";
}

sub decrypt {
 my $str =<>;
 my $key =<>;
 my %map = ( $key =~ m/(\d+)$consonants/g );
 my $index = 0;
 my @result = map{ $map{$index++} || (), $_ } split //, $str;
 print join '', @result;
}
```

Comment: Your output has deleted the numerals from the input viz. T-800 and Terminator 2

Comment: @Manav fixed. All 3 versions work correctly with numbers :)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl (126+67=193 characters)

Key contains each character removed along with its offset.

Encrypt reads one line from STDIN

Decrypt reads two: first the ciphered string then the key

```
sub encrypt{$_=<>;s(.)(++$j,$q|=$&=~/[aeiou]/i,$q^=$&eq$",!$q&$&=~/[a-z]/i&&(push@d,($&,$j-1))||print$&)ge;print$/.join',',@d}
sub decrypt{$q=<>,$_=<>;s/(.),(\d+)/substr($q,$2,0)=$1/gie;print$q}
```

Examples:

```
(encrypting)
The most technologically efficient machine man has ever invented is the book. -Northrop Frye-
> e ost echnologically efficient achine an as ever invented is e ook. -orthrop e-
> T,0,h,1,m,4,t,9,m,35,m,43,h,47,t,68,h,69,b,72,N,79,F,88,r,89,y,90

"I need your clothes, your boots and your motorcycle. " - The T-800 in Terminator 2: Judgment Day
> "I eed our othes, our oots and our otorcycle. " - e -800 in erminator 2: Judgment ay
> n,3,y,8,c,13,l,14,y,22,b,27,y,37,m,42,T,58,h,59,T,62,T,71,D,94

(decrypting)
e ost echnologically efficient achine an as ever invented is e ook. -orthrop e-
T,0,h,1,m,4,t,9,m,35,m,43,h,47,t,68,h,69,b,72,N,79,F,88,r,89,y,90
> The most technologically efficient machine man has ever invented is the book. -Northrop Frye-

"I eed our othes, our oots and our otorcycle. " - e -800 in erminator 2: Judgment ay
n,3,y,8,c,13,l,14,y,22,b,27,y,37,m,42,T,58,h,59,T,62,T,71,D,94
> "I need your clothes, your boots and your motorcycle. " - The T-800 in Terminator 2: Judgment Day
```

Ungolfed with comments

```
sub encrypt{
    # get input
    $_=<>;
    # for each character
    s(.)(
        # increment j
        ++$j,
        # set q to 1 if vowel
        $q |= $&=~/[aeiou]/i,
        # set q to 0 if space
        $q ^= $& eq $",
        # if q==0 and is a letter (consonant, because q=1 if vowel)
        !$q & $&=~/[a-z]/i &&
            # push both the letter and the offset to @d
            (push @d,($&,$j-1))
        # otherwise print
        || print$&
    )ge;
    # print a newline, then @d
    print$/.join',',@d
}
sub decrypt{
    # read a line to $q, and another to $_
    $q=<>,$_=<>;
    # for each [character],[number] in key
    s/(.),(\d+)/
        # add character back into string
        substr($q,$2,0)=$1
    /gie;
    # print deciphered string
    print$q
}
```

Comment: why have you hardcoded `$_="s,4,t,5,b,11";`. Can you make a generalized solution.

Comment: @Manav fixed. Forgot to remove that when posting.

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell: 119 = 111 + 8

Since there's no restriction on the key, I'm going agile and not getting any more complex until someone has a shorter answer:

```
e t=(unwords.map((\(a,b)->filter(not.(`elem`['a'..'z']++['A'..'Z']))a++b).break(`elem`"aeiouAEIOU")).words$t,t)
d(c,k)=k
```

I can make this at least 6 characters shorter if I import isAlpha from Data.Char. It's part of the standard distribution, so is it allowed?

Comment: How do I test this?

Comment: Install Haskell, use `ghci` for a console, paste in the functions (in GHCi you'll need to precede each with `let `, call as `e "200-storey building"` and `d ("200-orey uilding", "200-storey building")`, which is what `e` should give you.